# QTreeWidget show child in the same level of parent

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to show child in the same level of parent. For doing this first made the dotted line disappear using fun

```
drawBranches();
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_treewidget->setIndentation( 0 );
```